# Hibernate: Merge and remove not deleting the entity object from the database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I've been trying to delete an entity object from the database. Using a query to get the object and delete it works. Using merge to get it returns the same object but doesn't delete it.

Works:

```
Example example = em.createQuery("from Example where id = :id", Example.class).setParameter("id", id).getSingleResult();
em.remove(example);
```

Doesn't work:

```
Example example = em.merge(obj);
em.remove(example);
```

I've also found that putting it in this order works:

```
em.createQuery("from Example where id = :id", Example.class).setParameter("id", id).getSingleResult();

Example example = em.merge(obj);
em.remove(example);
```

.equals returns true for both of them. Using Hibernate JPA  2.1.

Comment: I guess is because the object you are using in the merge method is not exactly the same you have in your DB

Comment: I think you should get the object using em.find() first.

Comment: I added another example which leads me to believe the objects are the same. It loads fine with a merge if the query is used first.